# ¿Llenar un formulario PDF desde Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, pdf, itextsharp, itext

Tengo un archivo en PDF el cual necesito llenar por medio de un formulario hecho en visual basic .net, he leído que es con la librería iTextSharp sin embargo no logro cómo hacer para poder escribir dentro del PDF existente por medio de código.

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, este codigo es de mi propia autoría, lo hice con la libreria que mencionas en un backgoundworker (le puse timer, debido al tiempo de espera de creación del pdf coloqué una barra de progreso).

[Código completo del trabajo](https://codeshare.io/2W68Ld)

Para responder a tu pregunta, para escribir en el PDF debes seguir estos pasos:
1.- Declaración de variables:

```
Dim oDoc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(PageSize.LEGAL, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Dim pdfw As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter
Dim cb As PdfContentByte
Dim fuente As iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont
Dim fuenteTitulos As iTextSharp.text.pdf.BaseFont
Dim NombreArchivo As String = "C:\tu ruta de almacenamiento.pdf"
Dim archivoTemporal As String = "C:\Windows\Temp\tu ruta de almacenamiento" & txbOtProyecto.Text & " " & lblAnioOt.Text & "(Temporal).pdf"
Dim tablaCabecera As New pdf.PdfPTable(1) 'Esto permite crear tablas
```

Luego debes declarar la instancia de documento pdf

```
Try
    If generaTemporal Then
                pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(oDoc, New FileStream(archivoTemporal, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            Else
                pdfw = PdfWriter.GetInstance(oDoc, New FileStream(NombreArchivo, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            End If
        Catch ex As UnauthorizedAccessException
            MsgBox("Error al generar o guardar el documento: " & ex.ToString(), MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error iTextSharp")
        End Try
```

Luego debes abrir el documento

```
'Apertura del documento.
           oDoc.Open()
            cb = pdfw.DirectContent
            'Agregamos una pagina.
            oDoc.NewPage()
            'Márgenes
            oDoc.SetMargins(28.5, 28.5, 70, 35)
            'Iniciamos el flujo de bytes.
            cb.BeginText()
            'Instanciamos el objeto para la tipo de letra.
            fuente = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, iTextSharp.text.Font.DEFAULTSIZE, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL).BaseFont
            fuenteTitulos = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, iTextSharp.text.Font.DEFAULTSIZE, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD).BaseFont
            'Seteamos el tipo de letra y el tamaño.
            cb.SetFontAndSize(fuente, 14)
            'Seteamos el color del texto a escribir.
            ' cb.SetColorFill(iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK)
```

Luego escribes el texto de la siguiente forma

```
cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, "Pauta de Chequeo", 310, PageSize.LEGAL.Height - 55, 0)
```

Al momento de terminar, siempre debes cerrar el documento.

```
'Fin del flujo de bytes.
            cb.EndText()
            'Forzamos vaciamiento del buffer.
            pdfw.Flush()
            'Cerramos el documento, fin pagina 2.
            oDoc.Close()
```

Y para cerrar el documento dentro del catch escribes lo siguiente.

```
Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error en GenerarDocumento(): " & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error generando PDF ")
            'Si hubo una excepcion y el archivo existe ...
            If File.Exists(NombreArchivo) Then
                'Cerramos el documento si esta abierto.
                'Y asi desbloqueamos el archivo para su eliminacion.
                If oDoc.IsOpen Then oDoc.Close()
                '... lo eliminamos de disco.
                File.Delete(NombreArchivo)
                MsgBox("Error en GenerarDocumento(): " & ex.ToString, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Error generando PDF ")
            End If
            Throw New Exception("Error al generar archivo PDF (" & ex.Message & ")")
        Finally 'De suma importancia estas líneas, las que vacian las variables de flujo.
            cb = Nothing
            pdfw = Nothing
            oDoc = Nothing
        End Try
```

En el link está el código completo.

Si te sirve la respuesta, no dudes en marcarla.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hace tiempo hice algo parecido, lamentablemente no tengo el codigo pero te puedo dejar el enlace con el articulo con el que me guie https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23105/Programmatically-Complete-PDF-Form-Fields-using-Vi

Basicamente tiene que crear tu formulario en PDF asignar los nombre de los campos, luego como te explica en el articulo los llenas usando

```
pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_01(0)", "1")
```

Donde f1_01(0) es el nombre de tu campo en el PDF

Para crear el formulario en PDF yo use adobe acrobat, pero tengo entendido que también es posible con Oppen Office